# How to use prepared statement to set fetch & offset values with PDO sqlsrv?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am trying to use prepared statement passing values using params to set offset and limit (next rows):

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM livro ORDER BY id OFFSET :offset ROWS FETCH NEXT :limit ROWS ONLY');
$statement->execute(['offset' => 0, 'limit' => 5]);
$livro = $statement->fetch();
```

Error returned:

> The number of rows provided for a TOP or FETCH clauses row count
>   parameter must be an integer.

But if I try hardcoding:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM livro ORDER BY id OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY');
$statement->execute();
$livro = $statement->fetch();
```

Works well
I know that using mysql it is necessary use `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false` to works on limit. But I've tried using sqlsrv and got an error:

> The given attribute is only supported on the PDOStatement object

Is there a way to use prepared statement to set fetch & offset values with PDO sqlsrv ?

My enviroment: Windows 10, PHP 7.3, MSSQL 2014

Comment: You probably need to specifically bind the parameters as integer i.e. `$statement->bindValue(':offset', 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);`

Comment: it worked ! But is there a way or config to "force" the type detection ?

Comment: You can use casting as in my answer below like `(int) $limit` for example.

Comment: Unfortunately no, PDO will always use string unless told otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM livro ORDER BY id OFFSET CAST(:offset AS INT) ROWS FETCH NEXT CAST(:limit AS INT) ROWS ONLY');
$statement->execute(['offset' => 0, 'limit' => 5]);
$livro = $statement->fetch();
```

Comment: This also works for Oracle >= 12c when using :offset and/or :limit without the cast causes an "Error in SQL statement: OCIStmtExecute: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" error. (PHP 7.4)

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the multiple ways of doing a prepared statements. Try this:

```
// You could have your values in variables (or hardcoded)
$offset = 0;
$limit = 5;

$statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM livro ORDER BY id OFFSET :offset ROWS FETCH NEXT :limit ROWS ONLY');

// Next you need to bind the values
$statement->bindValue(':offset', (int) $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$statement->bindValue(':limit', (int) $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT); 

// Now execute your statement
$statement->execute();
```

When you use `?` instead of something like `:limit` you can then pass an array of values to execute and it will handle the binding automatically -- but this way allows you to force a data type.

Read More: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

---

In regards to your comment, you can try the following, but if I recall correctly the last time I had tried it with LIMIT and OFFSET it wouldn't work. Something janky in the implementation I suppose. Give it a try anyway:

```
$offset = 0;
$limit = 5;
$q = "SELECT * FROM livro ORDER BY id OFFSET ? ROWS FETCH NEXT ? ROWS ONLY";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([$offset, $limit]);
```

Comment: thanks ! But is there a way to works like mysql and postgres without using two bindValue?

Comment: Factual check. Both ? and :mark work exactly the same in every way, so any suggestion involving changing one for another is not going to help